# Exponential of a symmetric, block tridiagonal matrix (with zero on the diagonal)

Tags: matrices, exponentiation

Is there an analytic result for the **exponential of a symmetric, tridiagonal matrix** (the diagonal can be zero, if this helps). Moreover, if it simplifies the result, the $\alpha$'s matrices can be (asymmetric) banded.

Here is an example of such a matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & \alpha_2 & & & \\
 \alpha_2 & 0 &  \alpha_3 & & & \\
& & \ddots & & \\
& & \alpha_{n-1} & 0 & \alpha_n \\
& & &  \alpha_n & 0
 \end{bmatrix}$$

I am aware that there are numerical means to do this (more or less accurate), *e.g.* most notably the software package EXPOKIT.

Comment: What does 'purely complex' mean? The above appears to be purely imaginary.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your notation, but what's wrong with $(I \cosh \alpha_2+\sigma_1\sinh\alpha_2)\oplus ... \oplus (I \cosh \alpha_n+\sigma_1\sinh\alpha_n)$, where $\sigma_1 =
    \begin{pmatrix}
      0&1\\
      1&0
    \end{pmatrix}$ is the usual Pauli matrix?